# .NET compact framework and ActiveSync

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, activesync, handhelddevice

Is there a way that my .NET CF app running on a Windows CE device can know when the device is docked/synced with the PC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See the following: Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status and ConnectionsDesktopCount. If ConnectionsDesktopCount is > 0 then you are docked to a PC.

See the the SDK sample here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158637.aspx for a demo of how to use Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is it.
Maybe, with WM 5.0 devices this could work, what about the older devices? They don't support this solution.